# ListView always has the same intent

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, android-listview

I have a ListView that is updated from a ASyncTask, The adapter updates the list properly, however my setOnItemClickListener always has the same data in the intent.

This is the code for the loop that populates the ListView

```
        if (JsonStr != null) {
                //Get list of courses
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(JsonStr);
                JSONObject Username = json.getJSONObject(InputUsername);
                JSONObject Courses = Username.getJSONObject("Courses");
                JSONObject CoursesItems = Courses.getJSONObject("items");

                //Iterate around all courses
                Iterator<String> i = CoursesItems.keys();

                while (i.hasNext()) {
                    final String key = i.next();
                    JSONObject Course = (JSONObject) CoursesItems.get(key);

                    //Create a course entry
                    Map<String, String> ListEntry = new HashMap<>(2);

                    ListEntry.put("code", key);

                    if (Course.has("m_name")) {
                        String CourseName = (String) Course.get("m_name");
                        ListEntry.put("title", CourseName);
                    }

                    if (Course.has("original_source")) {
                        String Source = (String) Course.get("original_source");
                        ListEntry.put("source", Source);
                    }

                    JSONObject Units = null;
                    if (Course.has("Units")) {
                        Units = Course.getJSONObject("Units");
                        ListEntry.put("Units", Units.toString());
                    }


                    ListEntries.add(ListEntry);

                    final JSONObject finalUnits = Units;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                                    getApplicationContext(), //Activity
                                    ListEntries, //List of pairs
                                    R.layout.mymodules__list_item, //Target Parent Layout
                                    new String[]{"title", "code", "source"}, //Key for pairs
                                    new int[]{R.id.list_item_alert_textview,
                                            R.id.list_item_date_textview,
                                            R.id.list_item_source_textview}); //target items

                            ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
                            lv.setAdapter(adapter);

                            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CourseActivity.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("Data", finalUnits.toString());
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            });

                        }
                    });
                }
        }
```

Comment: can you see the updated values on list???

Comment: yes, it updates the UI but all the list items have the same intent data

Comment: Well, you are supplying a final member field as extra. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'finalUnits'  is  final value .
move listener and data(List Units) to inside adapter.
and set listener in bindview method.

{

Intent i = new Intent(context,CourseActivity.class);

i.putExtra("Data",list.get(position).toString());

startActivity(i);

}

Answer (score 0):

```
just replace by this code onitemclick            
       lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                  @Override

       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?>parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        String value = (new ArrayList<String>(ListEntry.values())).get(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CourseActivity.class);
                                            intent.putExtra("Data", value);
                                            startActivity(intent);
                                        }
                                    });
```